# Преобразование выходных данных консоли в строку

Tags: c#, консоль

С#. Был произведен многократный вывод в консоль. Можно ли построчно считать в строку, что было в неё выведено?

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под выводом в консоль? Если ваша программа выводит в консоль, зачем этот вывод считывать - эти данные уже были в вашей программе?

Comment: Согласен, это абсолютно не рационально. Нужно очень много переделывать будет, поэтому и задаю вопрос. Под выводом в консоль - имею: Программа отработала, вывела в консоль построчно все цвета радуги. Мне нужно чтобы все они записались в массив строк

Comment: Скажем так, считать, что было выведено, думаю, можно, но я вам это советовать не буду, так как лучше порефакторить программу, чем сделать всё ещё хуже

Comment: спасибо) пойду переделывать)

Comment: @ЕгорПатуткин а почему нельзя записывать в  массив значения перед выводом?

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, что-то выводится в консоль:

```
Console.Write("Hello ");
Console.WriteLine("world!");
```

У консоли есть свойство `Console.Out`, имеющее тип `TextWriter`. Можно задать любой объект этого типа, в который будет происходить дальнейший вывод.

```
// сохраняем первоначальное значение
var oldOut = Console.Out;

// создаём объект наследник TextWriter'а
var sw = new StringWriter();

// задаем его для консоли
Console.SetOut(sw);

// теперь вывод будет направляться в StringWriter
// в консоли ничего не будет появляться
Console.Write("Hello ");
Console.WriteLine("world!");

// восстанавливаем предыдущий контекст
Console.SetOut(oldOut);

// посмотрим, что там у нас имеется
Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
```

---

Можно перенаправить вывод консоли прямо в файл, задав `StreamWriter` в качестве объекта вывода.

Comment: Спасибо! Так а куда у вас в итоге всё записывается?

Comment: @ЕгорПатуткин - Записывается в `StringWriter`. С его содержимым потом можно делать что угодно. Я для примера вывел его опять-таки в консоль (можете этого не делать).

Comment: Спасибо огромое!